# As a Front-End Developer, How to Pivot into Back-end Development?

Tags: job-change

I'm a **mobile application developer** with **7 years** of experience, currently unemployed, aspiring to **pivot into a back-end development** position. I do fiddle and experiment with some back-end development stacks on the side, but I believe the lack of professional experience might turn away most recruiters.

Given the situation,

1. Do you have an advice on how I should prepare myself to suit the position?
2. Do you think I have to resort to restart my career from an entry-level position?

Comment: can you ask at work to start working-pair programming with the back-end guys? That would be good experience

Comment: @scampi: "can you ask at work" ... Probably not, as the OP states that they are currently unemployed.

Comment: Pivot to backend? Not likely. More like sudden stop, break an ankle, recover in hospital, months of therapy to learn how to safely turn in a new direction, gain confidence too early, overexert oneself, re-break ankle, decide that your comfort zone was safer or put in the time to not re-break ankle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think I have to resort to restart my career from an entry-level position?

That actually the most important question. We cannot answer that for you, because we do not know in detail what you know.

However, consider this extreme example: you are the greatest guru in mobile applications. And you are sick of using computers, and you decide to become a shoes-maker. What chances will you have to perform as the greatest guru in shoes-making, from day one?

**Bottom line:** you might need to accept a lower "rank" for a while, until you get up-to-speed with your new job. Good luck. And until you get that dream job, keep improving your skills, so you can sell yourself better during the interviews. The company might accept to give you a high rank for your psychological comfort, but they might be ready to pay you only according to your skills - which is expected.

Comment: This is a really poor comparison - switching between front-end and backend programming has a huge amount of transferable skills - from programming itself, to testing and project leadership approaches. Switching to a whole different industry isn't.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have an advice on how I should prepare myself to suit the position?

Pick a back-end language and database and start learning from tutorials and blogs. Find some open source projects to contribute to.

Not sure what language you've done, but some back-end technologied may be easier to pick up depending - for example, experience with javascript would lend itself to working with node. Other language experience may point to PHP - if you do this, maybe pickup Symfony or Laravel as a framework - they're both in strong demand and pay well.

> Do you think I have to resort to restart my career from an entry-level position?

Probably not a complete restart, especially if you can create or contribute to a couple of projects. You've already got some developer experience and skills. But you might have to take a short step back, first. It's not a great time right now, but if you can get to meetups and start networking, you might have an easier time than applying for positions.

A back-end developer who has some experience in the  front-end is highly desirable for employers, even if you're going into a role that is 100% back-end.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it wold be a smoother transition for you to move to full-stack developer

Look this post up:
Don`t know if link posting is allowed, if not remove it please
https://blog.udacity.com/2014/12/front-end-vs-back-end-vs-full-stack-web-developers.html

Choose the back-end tool/ framework and get acquainted with it.
There is so much information on-line these days to learn your chosen path.

Getting certified in that chosen tool wold help your transition
Lack of experience may be offset by the certification in the areas where you feel less comfortable